# Gnome fallback panel Color

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome

I'm running fedora 19 and I want to use the gnome fallback (classic) mode but I don't like the panel colors. I want black panels and in gnome 2 you can configure them but not in gnome fallback. How do I change it?

Answer (score 0):

I too am running Fedora 19 and thought I wanted to use Gnome Fallback mode.  However after using it for a while, and looking at other desktops, I decided on MATE and have been using it for quite a while.  MATE is a fork of Gnome 2 (which is probably what you like) and has all the features I want (maybe you too!).

You may just want to drop Gnome desktop completely and install MATE.

```
# yum group install 'MATE Desktop'
```

You can have as many desktops as you want so there's no harm in trying them.  You don't even have to uninstall one desktop to try another - you just select the one you want at login.